# DataSet.Copy vs Dataset.Clone

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me `DataSet.Copy()`  vs  `Dataset.Clone()`
Also let me know some scenario's where we can use these

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Clone` will create a new, empty DataSet with the same schema (tables and columns) as the old one.  The new DataSet will not have any data.

`Copy` does the same thing, but also copies the rows in the tables.

Answer (score 4):

Clone copies the only the structure of the dataset where as Copy copies the data as well.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/ViewForum.aspx?ForumId=52327

Answer (score 3):

The `Clone()` method creates a new DataSet with the same structure.  The `Copy()` method does too, *and* copies the data.

Answer (score 0):

[DataSet.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.copy.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...) copies both the structure (tables, relations etc) and the data.

[DataSet.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clone.aspx) copies only the structure of the DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

.Clone returns a data set with exactly the same schema but without any rows, .Copy returns both the schema and the rows.